# How can i create a different shape floating action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am trying to get a floating action button but in a different size, I have tried some links but none of them worked. Any help would be great

I have tried code and I was tried to take an image view above bottom navigation view. But after clicking on the fragment, it was disappeared.

[image]

```
 <com.jediburrell.customfab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabType="custom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:fabShape="@drawable/fab_teardrop"
        app:fabColor="@color/red" />
```

I am trying to make a fab with oval shape

Comment: Please elaborate the problem

Comment: Why are you using a third party library? You can use the regular Floating Action Bar and just set a drawable as the background.

Comment: But why you want oval shape?

Comment: tried.. but this icon was showing inside the button

Comment: @SumitShukla requirement it is

Comment: @VK share your shape file

Comment: You can just use regular ImageButton, if Fab doesn't work out for you.

Comment: Using the regular Floating Action Bar with custom drawable as the background should met your requirements

Answer (score -1):

Below is workign code

**oval.xml**(shape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />


</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        app:backgroundTint="@drawable/oval" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know for more help